# Terraform aws_iam_role_policy_attachment

Tags: terraform

I have some roles that i'm creating along with different policies, i'm not trying to tie them together:

```
#Role that gets created in in identity account that okta uses to map AD groups to Roles in AWS
resource "aws_iam_role" "create_identity_role" {
    count = "${length(var.team_name)}"
    name = "${lookup(var.identity_role_name,element(var.team_name, count.index))}"
    assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.trustokta.json}"
}

#Role that gets created in each of the accounts that will determine what it is a user will be able to do inside AWS
resource "aws_iam_role" "create_assume_role" {
    count = "${length(var.team_name)}"
    name  = "${lookup(var.assume_role_name,element(var.team_name, count.index))}"
    assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.trustawsaccount.json}"
}

#Policy that gets created in the identity account which tells AWS which role to assume in a different account
resource "aws_iam_policy" "create_assume_policy" {
    count = "${length(var.team_name)}"
    name  = "${lookup(var.assume_role_name,element(var.team_name, count.index))}"
    policy = "${data.template_file.network_assume.rendered}"
}

#Tie my role and polocies together
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_assume_policy" {
    count = "${length(var.team_name)}"
    role = "${lookup(var.assume_role_name,element(var.team_name, count.index))}"
    policy_arn = "${element(aws_iam_policy.create_assume_policy.arn, count.index)}"
}
```

The issue I'm coming across is when the policy goes to attach itself to a role, i'm not so sure I know what variable I should pass into policy_arn in the final resource so that it iterates through for each policy it created in the resource right before it.

Error upon terraform plan: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, resolved with using a splat:

```
#Tie my role and polocies together
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_assume_policy" {
    count = "${length(var.team_name)}"
    role = "${lookup(var.assume_role_name,element(var.team_name, count.index))}"
    policy_arn = "${element(aws_iam_policy.create_assume_policy.*.arn, count.index)}"
}
```

Comment: Hi duhaas, what is a "splat"?  I see the code but I'd love to understand it better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See explanation on splat here: https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9

and here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html